# Serverless packaging problems with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, serverless-framework

I developed a lambda function in plain JavaScript which uses the following node modules:

- knex
- mysql
- stripe

When I deploy this project it has about **3.94 MB**.

I recently switched to TypeScript and added the following additional DEV dependencies:

- serverless-plugin-typescript
- @types/aws-lambda
- @types/node

When I deploy it now, it has **15.11 MB** which is kind of strange, since I only added dev dependencies. As default serverless usually excludes dev dependencies, but in my case it seems that something is wrong with that config.

Has anybody discovered a similar problem with serverless and typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Serverless Webpack plugin and in the includeModules(serverless.yml) configuration include the package.json `custom: 
    webpack:
        webpackConfig: 'webpack.config.js'   # Name of webpack configuration file
        includeModules: 
            packagePath: './package.json'   # Node modules configuration for packaging
        packager: 'npm'   # P`